# JAX-RS problems when uploading excel file with POST

Tags: rest, jax-rs, tomcat7

I'm developing a POST method that must receive an excel file, but I have some problems. This is my code

```
@Path("/rest")
public class RestManager{
    [...]

    @Path("/uploadFile")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @POST
    public Response uploadFile(FormDataMultiPart multipart){
        [...]
    }
}
```

When I call the API, on server side I have the following error:

```
ott 09, 2017 4:58:48 PM org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor aroundReadFrom
GRAVE: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=multipart/form-data, type=class com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, genericType=class com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart.
```

In my web.xml, I added the following code:

```
   <init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
      <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

I'm running on Tomcat v7.0 and I added jersey-multipart-1.18 and mimepull-1.9.3 to manage Multipart data.

My client response obtain 415 Unsupported Media Type, but in the code I use to send the request I for the request 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', accordingly with the @Consumes annotation.

Can anyone give me hint to understand where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong `FormDataMultiPart`. The one you're using is from Jersey 1.x jar, but you should be using the one from Jersey 2.x. The jar is `jersey-media-multipart`. Once you add this jar and remove the 1.x jar, the package name of the `FormDataMultiPart` will be different. You will need to import it from `org.glassfish.jersey.multipart`.

Another thing, depending on what Jersey (minor) version you are using and the `jersey-media-multipart` version you are using, the `mimepull` version will also be different. Check out [this link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-multipart) and click the version that you are using. Then scroll down to "Compile Dependencies". You will see `mimepull`. This is the version you will need that is compatible with the `jersey-media-multipart` version you are using.